# Is it a good idea to store css classes in php strings when sending html emails through php

Tags: php, html, css, email

Some email providers like gmail do not support css classes when sending html email through php, so I thought i would store css classes or even full codes in php strings so I can use them multiple times. For example

```
    $leftbox = '<div style="background:#333;border:1px solid #000;padding:5px 2px;float:left;width:200px;">';
$rightbox = '<div style="background:#FFF;border:1px solid #CCC;padding:5px 2px;float:right;width:200px;">';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$message = '<html><body style="background:#000;margin:auto;width:400px;">';
$message .= $leftbox.'Name </div>'.$rightbox.' Content 1</div>';
$message .= $leftbox.'Addresss </div>'.$rightbox.' Content 2</div>';
$message .= $leftbox.'Mobile </div>'.$rightbox.' Content 3</div>';

mail("emailadress@email.com", "Subject", $message, $headers);
```

Is this a good idea, or is there any other good ways to do this if you want a good looking html email sent with php?

Comment: *"Some email providers like gmail do not support css classes when sending html email through php"* - That's false and has changed https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css. You just can't use an external source.

Comment: well, I did try to use it yesterday and didn't show up on gmail, it just show plain text, but it works with hotmail. and I came to here and look through lots of questions and all I found is gmail supports only in-line emails. its a simple code. and then I use inline css for that and it works on gmail.

Comment: there isn't enough code to support the question and how you're sending that mail

Comment: I personally don't see any problem with it. A rather unusual method, but making email templates that render correctly on every mail client is very tedious so whatever works is okay. Only thing I'd do differently is, for readability purposes, keep only the styles themselves in the variables.

Comment: use a full doctype declaration, with full HTML markup tags. Your present markup is invalid.

Comment: @Pejka yeah thats a good idea.

Comment: @Fred -ii- using full doctype declaration, with full HTML markup tags did work. thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with an inline style sheet? For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background:#000;
    margin:auto;
    width:400px 
} 
.leftBox {
    background:#333;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px 2px;
    float:left;
    width:200px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="leftBox">Something in the left box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Just had a look at some HTML email on 'Inbox' and you may need to include a `<!DOCTYPE html>`tag. Other than that, the above code "works for me".

Comment: it does not work with gmail. you need inline css to do that when sending emails with php.

Comment: How does eBay, Amazon do it then? See edit. Included `<!DOCTYPE html>` and that seems to be all that everyone else does.

Comment: In the past, inlining was absolutely necessary. It may no longer be.

Comment: Using full doctype declaration, with full HTML markup tags did work. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes it is the little things :]

Comment: yeah agree. looked for this everywhere. glad I asked to question.